# How to trigger Timer.publish() right away?

Tags: swift, combine

I created a [timer via combine](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer) which emits `Date` and ignores errors using this code:

```
let timer: AnyPublisher<Date, Never> = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: RunLoop.Mode.common)
  .autoconnect()
  .map { _ in Date() }
  .replaceError(with: Date())
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

(I'm sure there are better ways than mapping and replacing the error, but for this example, I wanted to keep the type simple, `AnyPublisher<Date, Never>`.)

The timer fires correctly, but there is a delay between when the timer is created to when it fires the first time (i.e. it waits 5 seconds). With [NSTimer, we can invoke timer.fire()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764168/how-to-trigger-nstimer-right-away) to force it to fire immediately.

Is there an equivalent way to force a timer to post immediately when using `Timer.publish()`?

---

Alternatively, is there a way to merge `Just(Date())` with the above `Timer.publish` so that it fires immediately and every 5 seconds, while still keeping the `AnyPublisher<Date, Never>` type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm sure there are better ways than mapping and replacing the error

`Timer.TimerPublisher.Failure` is `Never`, so you don't need any mapping because it can't fail.

Furthermore, `Timer.TimerPublisher.Output` is already the current `Date()`, so you don't need to `map` the output either.

To emit the current date immediately on subscription, you want to combine a `Deferred { Just(Date()) }` with the timer publisher. The `Deferred` means the current date won't be computed until the subscription happens.

Here is one way to put it all together:

```
let timer = Deferred { Just(Date()) }
    .append(Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect())
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Great point about `Deferred`. Also for other scenarios, it seems like `Publishers.Merge` is another solution, but `append` sounds more accurate for this situation.

Answer (score 15):

Also, there is an option using [prepend](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/prepend(_:)-v9sb)

```
let delayPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common)
  .autoconnect()
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .prepend(Date())
```

Comment: I think simplest solution so far, not need to merge with another publisher when you can just add an initial value

Answer (score 6):

Alternative to @rob mayoff answer and @Senseful comment, it's possible to merge the "first value" of the timer doing:

```
let delayPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common)
  .autoconnect()
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .merge(with: Just(Date()))
```

Comment: Far more simpler alternative. +1.